# How to embed Youtube premieres into my web site?

Tags: youtube

I upload a video to Youtube and set as premiere, it can be played normally, but when i copy embedding code and paste it to my web site, there appeared an error `Playback on other website has been disabled by the video owner`.

I tried to enable the Embedding option in Youtube video settings, but seems like it can't be enabled until the premiere is end.